# Wrong drawable assigned to button after using setEnabled(false) and setEnabled(true)

Tags: android

**Basic idea:** I have a button with *drawable1* assigned. When button is pressed *drawable2* is assigned.

**What my code does:** On release of *button1* it is set to setEnabled(false), fullscreen *ImageView* and *button2* is shown on top. On click of *button2* the *ImageView* is set to null, *button1* is set to setEnabled(true), *button2* is set invisible.

**Unwanted behaviour:** After *button2* is clicked *button1* has *drawable2* assigned even though it is not pressed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true"  
        android:drawable="@drawable/capture_button_pressed" /> 
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/capture_button" />    
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/capture_button" />
</selector>
```

-

```
maCaptureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
maCaptureButton.setOnTouchListener(
    new View.OnTouchListener() {
         @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ...
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                maCaptureButton.setEnabled(false);
                maImageView.setImageBitmap(...);
                maBackButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }       
);

maBackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_back);
maBackButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            maImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
            maBackButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            maCaptureButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
);
```

I've been struggling with this problem for a few hours. Everything worked fine until I added setEnabled(false) and setEnabled(true) in my code.

Comment: So you only want 2 states: pressed and normal? Just remove `enabled` from evey item and remove the last one (which is now equal to the second one). Done.

Comment: It doesn't work. The issue remains the same.